# Как сделать постоянно изменяющийся текст в TextView (Android)? Задержка в Android без остановки работы остального интерфейса

Tags: java, android

Сразу пример, чтобы было понятно:

{<отображается "123"> - <проходит секунда> - <отображается "231"> - <проходит секунда> - ...}

В коде:

```
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    textView.setText("123");
    //delay
    textView.setText("231");
    //delay
}
```

Судя по тому, что я начитал к этому моменту про Handler'ы, Timer'ы и потоки, мне нужно выделить на эту постоянную смену текста отдельный поток и проводить манипуляции по задержке уже с ним. Как его выделить и манипулировать им?

P. S. Если есть другие способы - пишите и их.

UPD: ниже часть кода, под который я хочу сделать эту задержку. Но я всё ещё хочу, чтобы она была универсальной и, желательно, была отдельной функцией.

```
while (!aliveText.getText().toString().equals(ethalone)) {
        String mid = aliveText.getText().toString();
        aliveTextTop.setText(formatWithEthalSpaces(mid, ethalone, setNewText(null, null, ethalone)));
        String top = aliveTextTop.getText().toString();
        //delay(1000);
        String cur = aliveText.getText().toString();
        aliveText.setText(setNewText(cur, top, ethalone));
        //delay(1000);
        aliveTextBottom.setText(top);
        //delay(1000);
    }
```

"Постоянное изменение" заключается в последовательной смене `aliveTextTop`, `aliveText` и `aliveTextBottom`

Comment: Другой пример (побольше, чтобы исключить недопонимания): <отображается "123">-<проходит секунда>-<меняем бекграунд приложения>-<проходит секунда>-<отображается "222">-<проходит секунда>-<отображается "322">-<проходит секунда>-<появляется поле для ввода текста>-<...>. Действия возможно непредсказуемые и не зависящие от счетчика таймера. Мне нужна универсальная задержка. Возможно заблокировать поток выполняющейся функции. Как это сделать?

Comment: Что имеете ввиду под "постоянно изменяющийся текст" ? У Вас будет генератор случайных чисел или по кругу будет перебираться какой то список значений или есть алгоритм который будет какой-то текст изменять перед следующим отображением? Уточняю, так как у Вас приведен цикл `for()` в вопросе, но как для "бесконечного" у него не хватает пару строк кода.

Comment: Покажите код который Вы уже сделали и напишите что именно не работает, или какая ошибка. А то по четырем строкам кода сложно представить с чем имеем дело.  И эти "НЕПРЕДСКАЗУЕМЫЕ действия" которые вы описываете в комментарии - вносят еще больше путаницы.

Comment: @V.March непредказуемые действия = мне нужна функция задержки. Я хочу вызывать не действие после задержки (как в Handler'е, например), а задержку как отдельную функцию. Универсальную и для конечного числа действий и бесконечного. Сейчас дополню вопрос кодом, посмотрите.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Итак, после долгих поисков и большого количества потраченных нервных клеток, я нашел, как мне кажется, самое оптимальное решение (так как, я полагаю, оно наиболее приближено к машинному уровню. Но на самом деле всё просто). Чтобы это понял даже человек, такой как я на момент подачи этого вопроса, немного разъясню:

Нам понадобятся `Handler` и `Thread` (а точнее `class XXX extends Thread`).

`Handler` - это (если коротко) мост между потоками. Он может отправлять в другой (в большинстве случаев основной) поток сообщения из того потока, в котором он был создан.

`Thread` - это, в свою очередь, как все уже догадались - поток.

Если мы хотим, чтобы действия с задержкой выполнялись независимо от основного потока, то есть параллельно (во время задержки и выполнения действий между задержками интерфейс и другие элементы доступны, а так же могут выполняться другие действия), то действия с задержкой нужно выкинуть в другой поток, чтобы проводить манипуляции уже с ним (если ты сейчас собрался уйти, чтобы найти более легкий способ, то можешь тормозить - более легкого способа нет. Но и этот не сложный).

Итак, рассмотрим на примере таймера (все нижеописанное применимо для любых действий, если вы поймете пример).

Запихиваем в свою прогу таймер и кнопку его активации, а также поток и хендлер. В моём случае - `TextView timer`, `Button button`, `Thread r` и `Handler handler` (объявляем внутри класса `Main`, чтобы потом инициализировать всё, кроме потока в `OnCreate`).

Также внутри класса `Main` инициализируем поток: поток - это, по сути любая функция (но реализуется она через хендлер), в которой может быть использована непосредственная задержка. Но с вьюшками (элементами интерфейса) можно работать только в том потоке, в котором они были созданы, то есть в основном. Для этого нам и нужен `Handler`. К `handler`'у мы можем обратиться из этого потока, а он в свою очередь пошлет сообщение в основной поток, который может работать с вьюшками. Так как мы можем тормозить поток, который мы собираемся инициализировать, то отправлять сообщения через хендлер мы можем в любое время.

Инициализация класса потока (внутри класса `Main`, не в `OnCreate`! Всё описывается как отдельные функции.):

```
public class NewThread extends Thread{
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(true) {
            handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
            delay(1000);
        }
    }
    //Задержка в мс
    private void delay(int millis) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(millis);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Как вы могли заметить - таймер бесконечный. В `run` посылаем `handler`'у сообщение и вызываем задержку. (Можно послать сообщение, вызвать задержку, снова послать сообщение, вызвать задержку и тд)

В `OnCreate` инициализируем таймер и кнопку (находим по id), надеюсь, все умеют это делать. Там же инициализация Хендлера:

```
handler = new Handler() {
        public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) {
            //здесь можно делать всё, что угодно на основе msg. Дальше расскажу, как.
    }
};
```

Для удобства таймер будет запускаться на кнопку, но если вам нужно сделать какой-то другой активатор, то это на ваше усмотрение. Если нужно начать таймер непосредственно при запуске - запускаете следующую функцию в `OnCreate`.

```
//функция нажатия на кнопку = функция активации таймера
public void startTimer() {
    r = new NewThread();
    r.start();
}
```

Инициализацию потока не обязательно помещать сюда, можно инициализировать в `OnCreate`, но по примеру поток запускается на кнопку, поэтому `r.start()` здесь.

В момент запуска потока происходит угадайте, что? Правильно! Поток запускается!

Когда поток запускается (запускается `run`), в `handler` отправляется `msg`, атрибут которого `msg.what` = 0 (мы сами его отправили)

На вход `handleMessage` у `handler`'а, как я понял, можно отправить только цифру (`msg.what`). Но на её основе можно (самое легкое) написать switch-case и вытворять всё, что угодно (я стремился сделать нечто похожее на матрицу и сделал с помощью switch-case на несколько TextView).

Так как наш пример можно написать независимо от `msg`, то вот код инициализации `handler`'a под наш пример:

```
handler = new Handler() {
    public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) {
        timer.setText((char)i);
        i++;
    }
};
```

При том, что `i` инициализирована в классе `Main`.

Также можно для этого использовать `msg`, но для этого нужно изменить `run()` нашего потока:

```
@Override
public void run() {
    while(true) {
        handler.sendEmptyMessage(i);
        delay(1000);
    }
}
```

(`i` так же объявлена в классе `Main`)
Тогда инициализация `handler`'а будет выглядеть так:

```
handler = new Handler() {
    public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) {
        timer.setText(msg.what);
    }
};
```

Остальное всё то же самое.

Обобщение: для того, чтобы события с задержкой выполнялись, не останавливая работу других элементов интерфейса и программы в целом, нам нужны поток (его можно останавливать, он не тронет остальной интерфейс) и хендлер (он отправит сообщение из нашего потока в основной для изменения элементов интерфейса, так как в нашем потоке их изменять нельзя). Если короче - мы держим сообщение хендлеру в потоке пока идет задержка. Когда сообщение отправляется - действие выполняется в основном потоке.

Преимущество в том, что вы можете отправить одно сообщение (вызвать один метод), после чего вызвать задержку и отправить другое сообщение (вызвать другой метод). Так как в нашем потоке нет ничего, кроме сообщения - он может висеть сколько угодно и это не повлияет на работу программы. Также после активации потока его задержку можно вызывать по условиям (например, если что-то в элементах интерфейса или в бэкенде изменилось, то поток может на это среагировать (если в нём запущен бесконечный цикл проверок) и сработать, вызвав задержку перед каким-либо методом). Что делать с этим дальше зависит только от вашей фантазии

P. S. Если `msg.what` - это `int`, то в switch-case `handler`'а можно вызвать до 2 * 2147483647 + 1 методов :)

Answer (score 1):

```
ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
int initialDelay = 0; // задержка перед первым выполнением
int period = 1; // задержка перед последующими выполнениями
 // view - твоя вьюшка, updateText - метод обновления текста на следующий в очереди
executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(view::updateText, delay, period, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать `Timer`. Довольно прост в применении.
Ниже адаптированный к вопросу кусок рабочего кода.

Принцип алгоритма, для примера, взял такой: Таймер каждую секунду запускает метод `changeTextView();` в котором происходит изменение текста в `TextView` и повышение значения инкремента `i`. При достижении `i >= count`  - таймер останавливается.

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class WaitConfirmActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Timer mTimer;
    private TextView textView;
    private int i = 0;
    private int count = 10;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_wait_confirm);

        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_view);

        mTimer = new Timer();

        startAlarm();

    }

    private void changeTextView() {

        //Пример алгоритма. У Вас же, естественно, будет свой алгоритм  счетчика.

        if (i < count) {


            if (i == 0) {
                textView.setText("123");
            } else if (i == 1) {
                textView.setText("231");
            }

        } else {
            cancelTimer();
        }

        i++;
    }

    private void startAlarm() {
        mTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                changeTextView();
            }
        }, 1000, 1000); //Первое значение - через сколько происходит запуск таймера, Второе - период срабатываний. В данном случае 1сек и 1сек.
    }

    private void cancelTimer() {
        if (mTimer != null) {
            mTimer.cancel();
            mTimer = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Не уверен, что полностью понял код, но вопрос не в этом. Вопрос такой: можно ли сделать задержку именно отдельным методом? Т.е. для любой "анимации" если можно это так назвать. Сделать так, чтобы я вызывал не метод после задержки, а, собственно, задержку отдельным методом? Как закомментированные строки в моем коде

Comment: Проблема в том, что ваш таймер всегда вызывает один и тот же метод. А я хочу просто сделать универсальный delay

Comment: @SimonGerasimenko У Вас ограниченное количество изменений Вашего активити?

Answer (score 0):

Рабочее решение:

```
TextView text_temp_all = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_temp_all);
Timer timer = new Timer();
TimerTask timerTask = new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                temp_all = temp_all + arrey_stats_cell[0][0][0];
                temp_all_string = String.valueOf(temp_all);
                text_temp_all.setText(temp_all_string);
            }
        });

    }
};
timer.schedule(timerTask, 0, 1000);
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]